# DataTables Jquery JSON

Tags: jquery, json, datatables

I am new to DataTables/JSON and I am running into a coding issues. The issue is trying to pull data information from one set of object array into another one; if I'm not explaining this correctly, please forgive me. I  can currently only pull data from the "courses" objects, but not the "schools". I need to render information from schools into courses. The plan is not to put the school names in multiple places but in one set of object arrays and pull the data that is needed depend on the id given under "courses" > "school"

**JSON txt file example**

```
{
   "courses" : [
       {
           "course_id" : "1",
           "course_title" : "Mathematics",
           "school" : [
               "1",
               "3"
            ]
           "cost" : "$100"
       },
       {
           "course_id" : "2",
           "course_title" : "Science",
           "school" : [
               "2",
               "3"
            ]
           "cost" : "$50"
       }
    ],
    "schools" : [
        {
            "school_id" : "1",
            "school_name" : "School of Mathematics",
            "school_info" : "You will learn more about math in this school",               
        },
        {
            "school_id" : "2",
            "school_name" : "School of Social Studies",
            "school_info" : "You will learn more about geography and how it plays a role in science",               
        },
        {
            "school_id" : "3",
            "school_name" : "School of Science",
            "school_info" : "You will learn more about math and science and how it relates to one another",               
        }
    ]
}
```

**JQUERY - DataTables**

The plan is to grab the numbers that are listed under "courses" (data) > "schools" to render out the name of the schools depending on the id number given

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var table = $('#example').DataTable( {
    "ajax": { 
                "url": "data/data.txt", 
                "dataSrc" : "courses"
            },
    "columns": [
        {
            "className":      'details-control',
            "orderable":      false,
            "data":           null,
            "defaultContent": ''
        },
        { "data": "course_id"},
        { "data": "course_title"},
        { "data": "cost" },
        { "data": "school" }
    ],
    "order": [] 
} );
```

**HTML**

```
<!-- DataTable Layout -->                
          <table id="example" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th>Course ID</th>
            <th>Course Title</th>
            <th>Cost</th>
            <th>Schools</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

**ADDITIONAL JQUERY** Datatables dropdowns based off [Datatable child rows](https://www.datatables.net/examples/api/row_details.html)

My additional task is to render the schools information on the dropdown verses the columns. So, when the user clicks on the course they can click the dropdown to get additional information about the school. Currently, the `format (d)` is only reading the first object `courses`, however, I want it to read both main objects such as `courses` and `schools` and render the school information depending on the ids. (Similar to how Tim Harker answered just within the dropdowns this time)

```
/* Formatting function for row details - modify as you need */
function format ( d) {



// `d` is the original data object for the row
return '<table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="padding-left:50px;">'+
    '<tr>'+
        '<td>Course Title:</td>'+
        '<td>'+d.course+'</td>'+
    '</tr>'+
    '<tr>'+
        '<td>School:</td>'+
        '<td>'+d.schools+'</td>'+
    '</tr>'+
   '</table>';
   }

// Add event listener for opening and closing details
$('#example tbody').on('click', 'td.details-control', function () {
    var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
    var row = table.row( tr );


    if ( row.child.isShown() ) {
        // This row is already open - close it
        row.child.hide();
        tr.removeClass('shown');
    }
    else {
        // Open this row
        row.child( format(row.data() )).show();
        tr.addClass('shown');
    }
} );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should get your fairly close:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var source = {
    "courses": [{
        "course_id": "1",
        "course_title": "Mathematics",
        "school": [
          "1",
          "3"
        ],
        "cost": "$100"
      },
      {
        "course_id": "2",
        "course_title": "Science",
        "school": [
          "2",
          "3"
        ],
        "cost": "$50"
      }
    ],
    "schools": [{
        "school_id": "1",
        "school_name": "School of Mathematics",
        "school_info": "You will learn more about math in this school"
      },
      {
        "school_id": "2",
        "school_name": "School of Social Studies",
        "school_info": "You will learn more about geography and how it plays a role in science"
      },
      {
        "school_id": "3",
        "school_name": "School of Science",
        "school_info": "You will learn more about math and science and how it relates to one another"
      }
    ]
  };
  var table = $('#example').DataTable({
    "data": source.courses,
    "columns": [{"data": "course_id"},
      {"data": "course_title"},
      {"data": "cost"},             
      {                
        "data": "school",
         render: function(data, type, row) { 
          var schools = '';
          $.each(data, function(index, value) {
            schools += ', ' + source.schools[value - 1].school_name;
          });
          return schools.substring(2);                
        }           
      }
    ],
    "order": []
  });
})
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.13/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css " rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.13/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js "></script>
<table id="example" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Course ID</th>
      <th>Course Title</th>
      <th>Cost</th>
      <th>Schools</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>
```

**UPDATE:**

Courses that belong to school...

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var source = {
    "courses": [{
        "course_id": "1",
        "course_title": "Mathematics",
        "school": [
          "1",
          "3"
        ],
        "cost": "$100"
      },
      {
        "course_id": "2",
        "course_title": "Science",
        "school": [
          "2",
          "3"
        ],
        "cost": "$50"
      }
    ],
    "schools": [{
        "school_id": "1",
        "school_name": "School of Mathematics",
        "school_info": "You will learn more about math in this school"
      },
      {
        "school_id": "2",
        "school_name": "School of Social Studies",
        "school_info": "You will learn more about geography and how it plays a role in science"
      },
      {
        "school_id": "3",
        "school_name": "School of Science",
        "school_info": "You will learn more about math and science and how it relates to one another"
      }
    ]
  };
  var table = $('#example').DataTable({
    "data": source.schools,
    "columns": [
      {"data": "school_id"},
      {"data": "school_name"},
      {"data": "school_info"},             
      {                
        "data": "courses",
         render: function(data, type, row) { 
          var courses = '';
          $.each(source.courses, function(index, course) {
            if (course.school.indexOf(row.school_id) > -1)
              courses += ', ' + course.course_title;
            });
          return courses.substring(2);          
        }           
      }
    ],
    "order": []
  });
})
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.13/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css " rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.13/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js "></script>
<table id="example" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>School ID</th>
      <th>School Name</th>
      <th>School Info</th>
      <th>Courses</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>
```

Let me know if you have any further questions, happy to help more.

Comment: Nice! That definitely helps me get to the right direction. I have a question are we able to make `var source` contain the ajax call to the script verses adding it in on the same page?

Comment: I figured it out. I appreciate your assistants! What I did was add `$.getJSON(url, function(data))` and included my datatable script inside with the function variable data having a `var source = data` . I had to do it that way because it was giving me a null or undefined otherwise. Thanks

Comment: I do have another question. I am actually using this type of DataTables: [https://www.datatables.net/examples/api/row_details.html] and I noticed my dropdowns aren't working, I will try to fix that issue. But the real question is if I wanted to add the school names on the dropdown section how would I go about doing it that way?
Also, if there is a better way to include the JSON txt data verses doing it the way I solved it, feel free to share :) Thanks!

Comment: Fixed the dropdown issue. I just added the needed javascript into the getJSON as well :) @TimHarker now I am working on the schools into the drop down. Thanks again.

Comment: Keep going, sounds like you are working through it nicely.  I'll keep my eye out for another question should you have it...  just include tag 'datatables' if/when you create another.  Keep up the good work!

Comment: I have another question: Based off the info above. Say if I was to create another page to list the schools, but this time I want to list the courses that belong to that school on one column. How would I loop through the JSON?

Comment: I updated my answer above.  If you find it useful, feel free to up-vote by clicking the up-arrow :-).  Let me know if you have anything else.  Happy to help again.

Comment: Thanks once again Tim! You are awesome! You save the day. I was so stumped on this. :D I want to upvote but to low on rep. xD

Comment: No worries, mate. Glad I could help.  Keep posting as things come up...